# How to trigger InputEvent after a text is been cut or pasted

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function that fires when the text area receives input from keyboard.

```js
let messageAttachmentSelector = document.querySelector('#action-attachment-selector');
let messageInput = document.querySelector('#action-input');
let messageSendButton = document.querySelector('#action-send');

messageInput.addEventListener('input',event=>{
    if( messageInput.value.length > 0   ){                    
        messageAttachmentSelector.classList.add("hidden");
    } else {
        messageAttachmentSelector.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
});
```

But the code is not firing when the messageInput value change using JavaScript.

I wanted to know, how I can receive JavaScript events for both keyboard and non keyboard changes.

Comment: _“But the code is not firing when the messageInput value change using JavaScript”_ - there is no event for the latter. If you need to react to _that_, then ideally you would do it from the place where the values gets changed already.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, but I'm still looking for a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because changing a field's `value` property is not considered "input" and so doesn't trigger the event.

There's various ways around this. One would be to trigger the native event when the value is programmatically changed.

```
let i = document.querySelector('input');
i.addEventListener('input', evt => evt.target.value += '!');
let evt = new Event('input');
i.value = 'foo';
i.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

[Fiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/781je5uy/).

Or, similar but without simulating events, you could make the event callback non-anonymous, so you can call it manually.

```
let callback;
i.addEventListener('input', callback = () => i.value += '!');
i.value = 'foo';
callback();
```

[Fiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/781je5uy/1/).

Comment: Worked, I made InputEvent to be dispatched where the input is changed by JS, thanks